Build Transaction to Transfer Native Token
I need to build a Cardano transaction that transfers a Native Asset/Token.
I am working in Go, using this library: https://github.com/echovl/cardano-go. I can see an example showing how to mint assets, but I can't see how to make a simple transfer transaction for native assets.
The asset to be transferred is Genius Yield Token.
I need to construct a transaction that sends (drains) Genius Yield Token from a set of UTXOs to a single address.
What additional fields need to be included for this?
Can someone explain (even generally) how to construct such a transaction?
Thanks in advance.
